# Back-light keyboard's lights are not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, brightness, 22.04, backlight

My backlight keyboard was working fine. I used to just use `xset led on` and the keyboard would just turn on its lights; however, after upgrading to 22.04. `xset led on` does not work anymore. I would be thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: that's because Ubuntu defaults to Wayland since 21.04, and `xset` is, as it sounds, an Xorg program. You can [switch to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857), and then it will work properly.

Comment: @Esther Thank you. Switching to Xorg solves the problem.

Comment: You can stay with Wayland https://askubuntu.com/questions/967373/wayland-equivalent-to-xset-led

Answer (score 0):

**This Steps works for me**

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/input12\:\:scrolllock/
brightnessctl -l
brightnessctl --device='yourdevice::kbd_backlight' info
sudo brightnessctl --device='yourdevice::kbd_backlight' set 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn on external keyboard baklight on ubuntu 22.04, follow the steps:-

Method to switch from Wayland to X ** this step is compulsory **
Edit the configuration file,

`sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

to uncomment [remove # from] the line containing

`WaylandEnable=false`

save the file (ctrl + x and after that y ('yes') or another key for non-English and finally Enter) and reboot.

Method One

1. open a terminal
2. `sudo xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'`
3. enter your password
4. press the scroll lock key to see if your back light comes on

Method Two

1. open a terminal
2. `xset led on`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
sudo xmodmap -e "add mod3 = Scroll_Lock"
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem (after ubuntu update) and eventually reverted to previous ubuntu to fix it.

For future reference, this log may be helpful if anyone runs into the same issue:

From `var/log/boot.log`:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
See 'systemctl status systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service' for details.


running systemctl gives:


systemctl status systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
● systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service - Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-backlight@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-05-30 10:22:21 PDT; 1h 44min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-backlight@.service(8)
    Process: 464 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-backlight load backlight:acpi_video0 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 464 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer. It would be better posted as a comment. If you've found a solution (which would be great), you should add this to your answer.